# Oracle Form Builder displaying blank page

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am trying to make a form using Oracle form Builder. I can connect to the database and create a basic form. The problem arises when I try to run the form.
It opens my default browser and just displays a blank page. Currently am running a VM with Windows Server 2003. I have tried the following:

- Firefox 2/3 (downgrades and upgrades). Also tried installing IE Tab 2 because someone said it might help.
- Downgrade to Internet Explorer 6.
- Install Oracle JInitiator.
- Modify the tnsnames.ora files.

The server is on the same VM. I have lost too many hours to this. Any suggestion?

Edit:
By request my formsweb.cfg : http://pastebin.com/A4Zqaqxu.
The only thing I changed in it (based on internet suggestion) is baseHTMLjinitiator from jinitiator to jpi.

Comment: Which version of Oracle Forms are you using?

Comment: Oracle Developer Suite 10.1.2.0.2. Think it's the latest.

Comment: Thanks, are you using OC4J or the full Oracle Application Server to run the form?

Comment: Excellent - Can you try compiling and running the test.fmb. In case of need it can be found @ oracle_developer_home\forms                  What happens?

Comment: Still white page. More so, recently (after how knows what I changed), the OracleDBConsoleorcl service fails to start. I read I needed to be in the same state of network connection as when I installed it for it to run. I can do this by cutting net to the vm.

Comment: Ok - when the white page is showing - is there a java console icon in the windows system tray?

Comment: Can you add to your question the contents of the formsweb.cfg? In case of need this can be found @ oracle_developer_home\forms\server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've moved our discussion to an answer as it makes it easier to read!

**Which version of Oracle Forms are you using?**

Oracle Developer Suite 10.1.2.0.2.

**Thanks, are you using OC4J or the full Oracle Application Server to run the form?**

The OC4J instance

**Can you try compiling and running the test.fmb. In case of need it can be found @ oracle_developer_home\forms What happens?**

Still white page. More so, recently (after how knows what I changed), the OracleDBConsoleorcl service fails to start. I read I needed to be in the same state of network connection as when I installed it for it to run. I can do this by cutting net to the vm.

**Ok when the white page is showing - is there a java console icon in the windows system tray?**

No, there isn't one

**Can you add to your question the contents of the formsweb.cfg? In case of need this can be found @ oracle_developer_home\forms\server**

By request my formsweb.cfg : http://pastebin.com/A4Zqaqxu. The only thing I changed in it (based on internet suggestion) is baseHTMLjinitiator from jinitiator to jpi.

**Ok - that parameter is one of several that controls which client JRE you are going to use, jpi is for the Oracle Sun JRE. From your original question it looked like you were using Jinitiator?
Can you change it back to basejini.htm. Is the browser that is opening up, IE6?**

**Update 27/04/2011
Sticking with IE6 and Jinitator, Exit Form Builder and stop the OC4J. Is JInitiator installed? If it is can you uninstall it using add\remove programs (or similar I don't have a copy of Windows Server 2003). Once it has been removed, Start Forms Developer and the OC4J instance and try running the test form again. What happens now? Are you automatically prompted to install JInitator?**

Comment: Changed it to jini. The browser now is FF 3. I have both JInitiator and JRE. Do I have to restart the Form Builder for the changes to apply?

Comment: No Form builder shouldn't need a restart, but can you start and restart the OC4J instance. (shouldn't need it but have seen in the past that it does!) Apologies I thought you were using IE. With regards to Firefox  - I'm not really sure what is required to get it working as you can see from this thread: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9523157&#9523157 there can a few hurdles that you may need to jump over to get it to work!

Comment: I'll use IE if I have to. That's not the problem. Will look over the link tomorrow. Too tired now. Thanks

Comment: Read my mind! No worries - the link is around the issues Firefox 3.x and JRE 1.3.X

Comment: In IE6 I get "The page cannot be displayed". Back to the drawing board.

Comment: The correct way of handling this problem is the following: Take the virtual machine from which you started, delete it, and get one that already has the programs you need pre-installed. I don't know what went wrong with my installation and I can't help anyone who was encountering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by starting OC4J via start menu instead of using the cmd.exe. :)